# Question about RecyclerView and onClickListener

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a working recycler view, and at the bottom, I want a toolbar where the user can navigate between the different activities. I set up an onClickListener for the images, but when running the programme, I cant click the images.

Did I include something wrong in my layout or did I order things wrongly?

[image: mypagelayout.xml]
[image: activity_main.xml]
[image: phone]

Answer (score 2):

i think what you need is android bottom navigation.
Have a look here: [bottom navigation](https://material.io/components/bottom-navigation)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [android bottom navigation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView#:%7E:text=Bottom%20navigation%20bars%20make%20it,to%20five%20top%2Dlevel%20destinations.) instead, which can solve your problem easily.

There is no much problem can be seen in your layout images, can you put relative code